# drive mountpoint automatic renaming

Tags: rename, mountpoint, automatic

[**What is causing this to happen every few months?**



BackinTime: "Can't find Snapshots location!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROV3x.png)

Comment: Never use backintime. Please show `getfacl /media/$USER`  normally udisks2 is mounting harddrives unter /media/your-user-name.   when the mountpoint is loosing its acl marks udisks can not  remove the folder. The next time by plugin it creates a new folder with a number as suffix.

Comment: You don't use BackinTime, or no one should use BackinTIme?
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/mgm
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mgm:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---

Comment: I mean I never use it. the permissions are okay.  ho did you start the backup? As user or in background over a cron job?

Comment: The main issue is not with RSync or BiT...the issue is the drive being backed up to has it mountpoint somehow automatically renamed intermittently.  You mentioned mountpoint folder security being changed...how it that happening...better how is it prevented?

Comment: Does anyone know if this was fixed in "20.04.1"?